# Two copies of iMovie app: can't get rid of the one "Installing" from the LaunchPad (other working from Finder)

Tags: install, software-update, imovie, launchpad, ventura

I have the following situation:

- In application Folder

[image: In application Folder]

- LaunchPad (stuck here ever since)

[image]

I found similar problems, such as:

- [iMovie update stuck with phantom app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/140037)
- [Mac App Store update stuck (Installing - Calculating...)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/82551)

, but none for `MacOS Ventura (13.1)`, none worked. Please leave your input to rectify this, thanks

**EDIT 2:** Now there's a XCode.app update but it's stuck at "Waiting...". Looks like I'm in trouble cause it won't move to any other App Store update unless this is fixed, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it's fixed now at last . I needed to do these three things:

1. [Reset Launchpad](https://www.imore.com/how-reset-launchpad)
2. Kill `installd` & `install in progress` from the Activity Monitor.
3. Restart Mac.